# Converting a word doc with images to HTML

Tags: html, ms-word, converters

I am hoping to find a program that will take a word doc pull the images to a folder and then link the images back into the word doc and convert it to HTML so I can upload it to our intranet site. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Use word itself. load .doc into word, `file -> save as`?

Comment: So I tried this right off the bat and it would work fine if we were creating new files and could link the images instead of insert them. Unfortunately we are dealing with files that are already created and have the picture inserted. Also MS-Word has really shitty conversion code.

Comment: anything office-related has ALWAYS had beyond craptastic html-handling code. But at least it never reached the level of adobe pagemill badness.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched Google?

If you know some html then you could use [this clean html converter](http://word2cleanhtml.com/) and then add in your images afterwards with img tags.

Example of an image tag

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" width="200px" height="300px" />
```

Comment: I know HTML the problem is the people that are going to be doing this don't so I am trying to streamline the shit out of it. I can get it to work but I fear they will think it is to complicated and complain.